Solr cell-level security
Is it possible for Solr to support cell-level security (think Hbase visibility labels)?
Was thinking there might be a way of structuring a Solr document with child documents that contain fields with a specific visibility.  And then using Solr document level security (using Ranger) to only permit the user to search/facet/retrieve the child documents they have visibility on within each parent document.
So for this document...
  {
    "id": "1", 
    "type": "parent", 
    "title": "Parent Document", 
    "childDocuments": [
      {
        "id": "1_1", 
        "type": "child", 
        "parent_id": "1", 
        "access": "everyone",
        "name": "me", 
      },
      {
        "id": "1_2", 
        "type": "child", 
        "parent_id": "1", 
        "access": "admin",
        "phone": "737-1111" 
      }
    ]
  }

... if I'm a regular user I can only search/facet/retrieve on the 'name' field but if I'm an admin user can search/retrieve the name and the phone number field.
I think I could get this to work.  I'm just not sure if I can support 'joined child document searches'.
eg. find all parent documents where the name='me' and the phone='737*' and return the parent documents with the children I have access to see.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbbtVQCezaU&list=PLU6n9Voqu_1FM8nmVwiWWDRtsEjlPqhgP&t=570s - this talk by Bloomberg shows how they solved a similar problem (where they even have in-column-content-permission). Might be a good start
